# Object.push doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am writing a PhoneGap/Cordova application using JQMobile.

I have a function that uses an object to push differences into an array like this:

```
alert( JSON.stringify(allAdj) ); //{"manche":"manch", "wollte","wollt"}
diffs = {};
for(key in allAdj) {            
    diff = key.slice(allAdj[key].length);
    diffs.push(diff);
}
```

This works fine in this instance.so I used it again later with another function:

```
alert( JSON.stringify(derP) ); //{"manche":"manch", "wollte","wollt"}
diffs = {};
for(key in derP) {            
    diff = key.slice(derP[key].length);
    alert(diff);
    diffs.push(diff);
}
```

But now it doesn't work! If I comment out the line "diffs.push(diff);" the diffs are alerted but if I don't comment it out only the first diff is shown and then the app stops.

For Javascript/jQuery bug finding I usually use Firebug but with a PhoneGap/Cordova app that is not possible. Can anyone recommend a debugging tool for PhoneGap/Cordova?

Comment: push is for array, should be diffs = [];

Comment: I heard about Weinre, a remote debugging tool for Phonegap/Cordova apps.

I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like it's what you're looking for.

 https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre

Answer (score 1):

You are using `push()` on an object.

> The push() method adds new items to the end of an **array**, and returns the new length.

Use an array instead of object.

**Example**:

```
alert( JSON.stringify(allAdj) ); //{"manche":"manch", "wollte","wollt"}
diffs = []; // array
for(key in allAdj) {            
    diff = key.slice(allAdj[key].length);
    diffs.push(diff);
}
```

---

*Reference*

- [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)